# amsmath's align* shifting parts of an equation to the right

Tags: align, amsmath

I'm completely new to LaTeX, and I ran into an issue when trying to align an equation with `amsmath`'s `align*` function.

My specific issue is that when trying to use multiple alignment levels, it sometimes leaves huge gaps in one line, but aligns fine in the next one.

Here's my code :

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    u_n&=\displaystyle\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n}\longrightarrow\
        \lim_{n\to\infty}u_n&&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n}\\
        &&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2(2+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})}{n^2(1+\frac{1}{n})}\\
        &&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}=2\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

And here's a screenshot:

[image: Example Screenshot]

Notice the conspicuous blank space.

Help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Off-topic: The `\displaystyle` instruction is redundant and does nothing but create code clutter. Delete it.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  There's already a good answer, but it doesn't mention explicitly that the last line of an `align` shouldn't end with `\\ `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit :

As precised in the comments, the goal was to be able to align the equations on several levels. For that, the environment `alignat` is used. Here, I created 3 columns. Each `&=` denotes an alignment and each `&` is used to tell where the columns are split.

**MWE :**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
    u_n     &=\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n}           &   &\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n       &   &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n}\\
            &                                   &   &                                   &   &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2(2+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})}{n^2(1+\frac{1}{n})}\\
            &                                   &   &                                   &   &=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}=2\\
    u_{n_k} &=\frac{2n_k^2+5n_k+1}{n_k^2+n_k}   &   &\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}u_{n_k}   &   &=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2n_k^2+5n_k+1}{n_k^2+n_k}\\
            &                                   &   &                                   &   &=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{n_k^2(2+\frac{5}{n_k}+\frac{1}{n_k^2})}{n_k^2(1+\frac{1}{n_k})}\\
            &                                   &   &                                   &   &=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{2+\frac{5}{n_k}+\frac{1}{n_k^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n_k^2}}=2
\end{alignat*} 

\end{document}
```

**Output :**

[image]

#### Original answer

That is because your `&`'s were not well placed, along with breaking lines.

With `align`, you place the ampersand (the `&` symbol) just before the equal sign you want to align. At the end of each line, add a breaking line symbol (`//`) to go to the next line.

Note: I replaced `\longrightarrow` with `\implies` because I find it better for logical syntax.

**MWE :**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    u_n=\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n}\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n}\\
        &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2(2+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})}{n^2(1+\frac{1}{n})}\\
        &=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}=2\\
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

**Output :**
[image]

Comment: That works, but what if I also want to align something with then original u_n? Like I have u_n = [...], u_n1 = [...], u_n2 = [...] etc. and I want them to be aligned too.

Comment: Than try `alignat`.

Comment: @Parashoo Is this a good example of what you want to achieve ? https://imgur.com/a/Pu5nORR

Comment: @Zarko I tried `alignat` too, and it did not change anything.

@Rphad Yes, that's what I'm going after.

Comment: @Parashoo Please check my edited answer. Don't hesitate to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem if some equations have a too long part in the first alignment column. In this case a better solution uses a nested `aligned` environment.

Here are  an illustrative examples: the first example, built with `alignat*{2}` works well, because the second equation is compatible. The second example uses the same structure, but has longer equation, and there is a blank space between the two columns. The last example use a single column, and a nested `aligned` in the r.h.s. of the first equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    u_n & =\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n}\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n& & =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n}\\
         & & &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2\bigl(2+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\bigr)}{n^2\bigl(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigr)}\\
        & & &=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}=2 \\
   v_n & =\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n}
\end{alignat*}
\vskip 1cm

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    u_n & =\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n}\implies&\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n & =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n}\\
         & & &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2\bigl(2+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\bigr)}{n^2\bigl(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigr)}\\
        & & &=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}=2 \\
   v_n & =\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n} + \Bigl(\sqrt{n^2 + n + 1}\Bigr)^{\!3}
\end{alignat*}
\vskip 1cm

\begin{align*}
    u_n & =\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n}\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n \begin{aligned}[t] & =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n}\\
        &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2\bigl(2+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\bigr)}{n^2\bigl(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigr)}\\
       &=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}=2
        \end{aligned} \\
   v_n & =\frac{2n^2+5n+1}{n^2+n} + \Bigl(\sqrt{n^2 + n + 1}\Bigr)^{\!3}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]